# Filter NSFetchedResultsController for nil value?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` which is fetching objects from a `NSManagedObjectContext`.

These objects have a `lastOpened` property, which is initially `nil` and is only set when they are viewed.

I want my `UITableView` to display a list of the most recently opened objects, which I can do by adding a `NSSortDescriptor` to the `NSFetchRequest`.

**Question:**

I don't want to display the objects which have never been studied. (`lastOpened == nil`) Can I sort this via the same `NSFetchRequest`? Is there a better way to filter the data?

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely. What you're looking for is an [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). Basically, it allows you to specify one or more conditions that you want your fetched objects to meet, then only fetches objects that match those conditions.

Building predicates is a slightly tricky proposition, however - you might want to take a look at the [Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) guide to get started. <strike>For your particular case, it's even trickier since I'm not sure there's a representation for the nil value in predicate terms. You can get around this, however, by using some date in the distant past:</strike>

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastOpened > %@",
                          [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]];
```

You can just check against nil directly in a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastOpened != nil"];
```

This creates a predicate that only allows objects with a set date (anything after January 1, 1970) to be returned. You'd then add the predicate to the fetch request before you execute it:

```
// Assuming you have some almost-ready NSFetchRequest *request:
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I had a hunch predicates were involved. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastOpened != nil"];
... // add sort descriptors etc.
```

Then add the fetch request to the `NSFetchResultsController`.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift, you can initialize NSPredicate with a boolean to always return true, effectively a filter that doesn't filter anything

```
return fetchedResultsController("Terminal", withFilter: NSPredicate(value: true), sortColumns: sortColumns, sortDirections: sortDirections)
```