# Deleting the core data entity

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am doing a project which involves a good use of core data. I have been using it since few months now. I have a small problem. I have two different entities a entity named Student and another named Courses. The relationship between Student and Courses is one to many. I am frequently updating the entities from the remote json. So, sometimes there are dangling pointer in the Courses entity which do not have relationship to the Student entity. This type of the entities need to be deleted. How is it better to delete such objects ?

```
              Courses(points to student) <------------- Student ----------------> Course (Points to student) 
                                                           |
                                                           |
                                                           |
                                                           |
                                                Course (Points to student)

                       Course(has no pointer to student, no foreign key to relate with student)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to delete a course when it has no students? Course may be valid though. I think you should nullify the relations, so when you delete a student, all courses pointing to it just would stop referencing that student.

You probably need to check your [relationship delete rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) so that they should be nullify in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, in this case it seems that deleting the course is weird. But, I have a similar type of the data structure in which the relationship when deleted the entity will have dangling columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to create a fetch request and query against `Courses`. Obviously you need to use a `NSPredicate` to remove the `Courses` with no students.

If your `Courses` has an inverse rel to `Student`, called `coursesToStudent`, you could set up the following predicate.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"coursesToStudent == nil"];
```

Here I suppose that `Courses` has a one-to-one rel with `Student`.

In this way the fetch request results will have `Courses` without a student. With the result, call `deleteObject` and you have done.

For info about setting a fetch request with a predicate see [Filter NSFetchedResultsController for nil value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070921/filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-for-nil-value).

About your model I would set up another one. For example use three entities:

```
Student
Course
Enroll
```

where

```
Student
- attributes you want
- toEnroll [one-to-many rel to Enroll with cascade rule]

Course
- attributes you want
- toEnroll [one-to-many rel to Enroll with cascade rule]

Enroll
- attributes you want
- toStudent [one-to-one rel to Student with nullify rule]
- toCourse [one-to-one rel to Course with nullify rule]
```

Hope that helps.